# How to get rid of 'grub rescue'?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uninstall, grubrescue

While logged into Windows, I deleted a disk partition which was containing Ubuntu. When I restarted my pc, it is showing 'grub rescue' command prompt.

How to boot windows now?

1. I no longer require Ubuntu.
2. I have Ubuntu live CD

When I tried the following commend:

```
sudo apt-get install lilo
```

the following error is shown:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main lilo i386 1:22.8-10ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lilo/lilo_22.8-10ubuntu1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair

Run Boot-Repair from a liveCD, click "Advanced options", tick "Restore MBR", click "Apply".

Comment: Although this may fix things, it's simply a band aid and fills your EFI partition with cruft once you start redoing it. The proper way is [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/304892/456878)

Answer (score 0):

Pop in your windows disc, click "Repair PC", run the autorepair, and finally, click something like "Repair Bootloader" (This may be done automatically).

This happened because GRUB is missing its boot data. It was on the Ubuntu partition.