# Grub 2 Problem - Removal not working!

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, partitioning, boot-repair

### Hello everyone, here is my problem

When I boot up my computer, I go straight into Grub 2. I know that if I type `exit` it will quit Grub 2. But for some reason it goes back into Grub 2, and I type the command in again and it exits again. At this point it does take me to the Windows (10) boot loader, which then let's me boot into Windows. Recently I thought enough was enough (I want to make my computer dual boot OS X and Windows), and decided to try and remove Grub 2 for good.

So, I then made a Windows recovery media. Booted into it and selected "repair Windows" or something similar. Then went into the advanced options and eventually I got to the console where I typed `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` and `bootrec.exe /fixboot` which both returned a "successful" message. But when I restarted my computer, minus my recovery media, Grub 2 appeared again but it was only one screen this time. I tried the same process as before to remove it; but the problem still persisted.

### What previous happened

At some point last year, I decided to install Ubuntu. Which I successfully did, and all was well for a month; until I decided I really don't need Ubuntu. Then I went into Windows and deleted the Ubuntu folder. And I know I should of used some kind of uninstaller to remove Ubuntu but I hadn't used it in about a week. And since then Grub has been haunting my computer, it's literally like Ubuntu  giving me the finger and say "you don't get rid of me that easily". And I was content Kathryn's haunting, and just keep typing in `exit` every time Grub raised its head.

---

I think it's somethings to do with my partitions. I have had a quick look and on the drive that I installed Ubuntu on, which also carries my Windows install, I can see three partitions. Two are unnamed, and one has a property called "EFI", so my guess is that's the heart of the problem. Unfortunately it won't let me touch it.., properly due to Windows being on the same drive.

Anyway, hope you can help 
                  Thanks for reading

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720 and more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/304558/uninstalling-grub-from-uefi-laptop and:Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you deleted the the partitions of ubuntu os. But still have entry in the boot menu. No Problem,You can use EasyBCD to remove the boot option. It have free non-commercial license for personal use. The instructions to use the software are also available on the site.

http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Comment: I will try that now and see if it works

Comment: Please let me know the result.

Comment: Well it's definitely a step in the right direction, I removed Grub and Windows 7 from my boot loader. Btw, I didn't remove the Ubuntu partition, I just deleted the Ubuntu  folder

Comment: Does using EasyBCD solve your problem. Are you facing the same problem after that?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, however the program has said k should disable secure boot and enable legacy boot mode

Comment: The program worked and solved half the problem. And then told me how to solve the rest of it. So thank you for the help! 