# Cloned dual-boot SSD to larger SSD. Deleted Ubuntu partition. Now laptop starts with "Minimal BASH-like editing"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, boot-repair

Recently bought a Lenovo T460s and dual-booted it with Ubuntu 14.04. Later, I decided to replace the 125GB SSD with a 500GB and cloned my hard drive using clonezilla. Because I had a linux partition in between the windows partition and the newly available unallocated free space from the new SSD, I couldn't fully extend my windows partition.

Therefore, I decided to completely remove Ubuntu and began by performing the following:

1. Deleting Linux partition via Disk Management
2. Boot laptop with Windows USB recovery
3. In Windows USB Recovery: Troubleshoot > Command Prompt > Entered: "bootrec.exe /fixmbr"
4. Reboot

After going through all the steps, I found that whenever I reboot my laptop, I would get the GNU GRUB "Minimal BASH-like editing is supported" screen. I've tried the steps listed in: https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/ to resolve this issue, however, it was ineffective.

Here is the pastebin URL from the boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23704623/

Does anyone have any other suggestions for me to try? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time

Comment: Just came across this related post. I'll be giving the answer post a shot

Comment: ^ http://askubuntu.com/questions/304558/uninstalling-grub-from-uefi-laptop/304892#304892

Comment: I seemed to have resolved my issue by just re-ordering the boot sequence on the BIOS. Now, the Windows Boot Loader is first in priority of boot order. I'm not 100% certain if this is a complete fix to my initial problem, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the Lenovo logo pops up on screen, press F1 to enter the BIOS.
2. Go to Startup > Boot
3. You should see a list of Boot Priority Order. In my case, I had ubuntu as first in line. Using the '+' or '-' key, re-order the boot sequence by making the Windows Boot Manager the first on the list.
4. Press F10 to save and exit. Reboot and your computer should load with the windows bootloader